# how to use valuemember and dispaymember in combox by linq?

Tags: c#, linq, windows

Here is my code but comboBox won't fill like I want. Can anyone help me?

```
var E = (

    from em in employee.Employees 
    orderby em.EmployeeID 
    select new { Names= em.FirstName,ID=em.EmployeeID }

        ).ToList();

comboBox1.DisplayMember = " Names";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DataSource = E ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in front of the string Names assigned to DisplayMember

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Names";
```

Comment: no it's not my problem my problem is  i can't display my employee in combobox with this code 
by member and value can u help me ?

Comment: the problem is it's display ID And Name in combobox and i want display only namee and the value is ID